# What's the most efficient way to use Roslyn's CompletionSevice when typing?

Tags: .net, roslyn

I'm looking at Roslyn's [`CompletionService`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features/Completion/CompletionService.cs,53), and `ShouldTriggerCompletion` is defined as

```
public virtual bool ShouldTriggerCompletion(
    SourceText text,
    int caretPosition,
    CompletionTrigger trigger,
    ImmutableHashSet<string> roles = null,
    OptionSet options = null
) { … }
```

where `CompletionTrigger` is a wrapper for a single `char Character`.

This seems to imply I should call `ShouldTriggerCompletion` on each char when typing — however that would mean I need to update `SourceText` on each char, which allocates an array of `TextChange`, a new `SourceText` and potentially other things depending on its internal structure.

Do I understand this API correctly? What is the most efficient way to use it when typing?

---

**Edit:** To clarify, I know I can second-guess it and only call it for let's say `.`. But my goal is to use the API the way it is intended to be used, without any optimizations other than those already provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> however that would mean I need to update SourceText on each char, which allocates an array of TextChange, a new SourceText and potentially other things depending on its internal structure

Yes, on each keystroke in Visual Studio we create a new SourceText and a new Document/Project/Solution snapshot. We have to do it since *all* features are depending on that Document instance existing.

For us, such an operation is cheap. The text editor component in Visual Studio already creates a cheap `ITextSnapshot` for each edit, which it does via very fancy data structures (think binary trees of pieces of strings) so this is as cheap as it can be. When we create SourceTexts for files in the editor, we instead create our [own derived type of SourceText](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text/Extensions.SnapshotSourceText.cs) and we just forward the requests for data to the editor `ITextSnapshot` API. It's not a coincidence that SourceText has effectively a subset of `ITextSnapshot`'s members, because we were designing for precisely this pattern!

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're trying to do.

If you are certain you know the completion triggers for your text, you can avoid having to call `ShouldTriggerCompletion` by triggering completion yourself whenever you think it's appropriate. But premature optimization isn't a good reason to reimplement it yourself. (You'll break compatibility with the other assemblies playing in the Roslyn sandbox; you might miss an edge case; you won't get upgrades when the language is upgraded; etc.)

---

*Also, if you're the caller, you probably shouldn't invoke `ShouldTriggerCompletion` directly: `GetCompletionsAsync` seems more likely to be what you want.*

Comment: Thanks. I'll update question to clarify, but my goal is to represent Roslyn standard behavior as close as possible, so I don't want to second-guess the API. I'm just used to throttling in typing operations, so I'm surprised to see multiple allocations not causing any problems here (though of course I should measure the actual impact).

Comment: Asked related question [What's the right way to update Roslyn's Document while typing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39422126/whats-the-right-way-to-update-roslyns-document-while-typing), since I'll need this for `GetCompletionsAsync`.