# What's the right way to update Roslyn's Document while typing?

Tags: .net, roslyn

What's the right way to update Roslyn's `Document` when user is typing new text? Should I call `SourceText.WithChanges` and then `Document.WithText` on each char, or is there a more efficient way?

Unfortunately throttling is not an answer, see my question [What's the most efficient way to use Roslyn's CompletionSevice when typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421668/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-use-roslyns-completionsevice-when-typing) where an API implies that `SourceText`/`Document` must be up to date on each char.

Comment: What's the context here? Are you implementing your own workspace, or are you consuming a workspace already provided to you?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski I'm creating my own workspace for my own editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing SourceText.WithChanges on each character is probably your best bet, assuming there's not a more efficient way you can create your own derived type of SourceText like we do in Visual Studio. (See my answer to your other question for that.) We have done a *bit* of work to make that not be too inefficient.

Comment: Thanks! Would be great to have an VS-like implementation included in Roslyn, but I think this is fair enough. I'll use `SourceText` and optimize if necessary.

Comment: "optimize if necessary" -- always the right approach!